# Cron expression for specific days using cron-utils

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am using [cron-utils](http://cron-parser.com/) jar for generating cron expression like:

0 0 0 ? * 1,3,7 *

At 00:00:00am, on every Sunday, Tuesday and Saturday, every month

How can i create the 'days of week' expression so it will be list and not only one value?

**Below is my code for above expression:**

```
CronDefinition definition = CronDefinitionBuilder.instanceDefinitionFor(CronType.QUARTZ);
CronBuilder cronBuilder = CronBuilder.cron(definition)
            .withYear(always())
            .withMonth(always())
            .withDoM(questionMark())
            .withHour(on(0))
            .withMinute(on(0))
            .withSecond(on(0))
            .withDoW(on(???????);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `and()` and you will be able to pass multiple days.

Example:

```
CronDefinition definition = CronDefinitionBuilder.instanceDefinitionFor(CronType.QUARTZ);
CronBuilder cronBuilder = CronBuilder.cron(definition)
            .withYear(always())
            .withMonth(always())
            .withDoM(questionMark())
            .withHour(on(0))
            .withMinute(on(0))
            .withSecond(on(0))
            .withDoW(on(1).and(on(3)).and(on(5)));
```